# PHP echo json with key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

why does this code not work correctly or what am I doing incorrectly?

```
$json = json_encode($myInstance->getData($id));
    $result = json_decode($json,true);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo '<div>'.$value[$i]['name'].'</div>';
        $i++;
    }
```

The first value is shown correctly but it doesn't iterate through!
Is `$value[$i]['name']` not build for iterating??
It Only prints the `array[0]` not the `array[1]`.  Thanks.

Comment: there is not enough information in this question for us to be able to help you. Please post a sample of the JSON.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without some associated JSON. Also some more information on `$myInstance`, specifically its method `getData`, would help.

Comment: Since it works correclty when I declare $i =1 the correct entry is shown of array[1]['name']. The json entries doesn't matter at this point. The problem is focused on $value[$i]  - why does it not iterate ? It should or am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using nested foreach loops, not generally great coding practice but it'll do the job you're trying to do.

```
$json = json_encode($myInstance->getData($id));
$result = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($result as $value) {
    foreach($value as $value_detail) {
        echo '<div>'.$value_detail['name'].'</div>';
    }
}
```

Your code will loop through all of the first level items in your JSON and display the first name from the first item, the second name from the second item, third from the third item, etc.

The issue you are having might be because the `$json` array is 3D, e.g.

```
[0 => 
  [ 
    ['name' => 'Foo'], ['name' => 'Bar'] 
  ] 
]
```

If that's the case then you might find that the foreach loop can be

```
foreach($result[0] as $value) {
    echo '<div>'.$value['name'].'</div>';
}
```

Try `var_dump($result);` to see what the data looks like.

Comment: Thats it awesome d3v_1 ! I just dont know why a nested loop is necessary at this point. i accept your answer asap. THX a lot :)

Comment: The data in $json might be a 3D array with the key of zero. I'll edit my answer to explain.